# How to inject a dialog into a service in Angular 9

Tags: dependency-injection, angular9

I want to inject a `MatDialog` into a service without initialize it into the constructor. Is it possible ?
If yes, how I can achieve this ?
The goal is to to call a service into a class and in that class I will have to inject MatDialog and other components later

Here's my implementation

```
ClassBook {
  private bookService: BookService = new BookService(); // no parameters hence the empty constructor

  public createBook(book: Book){
     this.bookService.addBook(book);
  }
}

export class BookService{
    constructor() { }
    
    // if i just call this, the this.dialog.open will be undefined
    public dialog: MatDialog;

 
    public addBook(book){
      const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(BookDialog, {
          width: '500px',
          disableClose: true
          data: {
             book
          }
      });
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I will use a static injector in the AppModule and then call it as singleton in the class i need